# Shadow on borderless elipse form

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

i would like to know if there is any way of making it so i can have an elipse form with a decently sized shadow around the form
here is an image of what it looks like now with the code that i use now:[Image of my current shadow form with elipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/updiu.png)

code:

```
        public class DropShadow
        {
            #region Shadowing

            #region Fields

            private bool _isAeroEnabled = false;
            private bool _isDraggingEnabled = false;
            private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
            private const int WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000;
            private const int HTCLIENT = 0x1;
            private const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;
            private const int CS_DBLCLKS = 0x8;
            private const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x00020000;
            private const int WM_NCPAINT = 0x0085;
            private const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C;

            #endregion

            #region Structures

            [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
            public struct MARGINS
            {
                public int leftWidth;
                public int rightWidth;
                public int topHeight;
                public int bottomHeight;
            }

            #endregion

            #region Methods

            #region Public

            [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
            [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
            public static extern int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref MARGINS pMarInset);

            [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
            [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
            public static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int attr, ref int attrValue, int attrSize);

            [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
            [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
            public static extern int DwmIsCompositionEnabled(ref int pfEnabled);

            [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
            public static bool IsCompositionEnabled()
            {
                if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6) return false;

                bool enabled;
                DwmIsCompositionEnabled(out enabled);

                return enabled;
            }

            #endregion

            #region Private

            [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
            private static extern int DwmIsCompositionEnabled(out bool enabled);

            [DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
            private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
            (
                int nLeftRect,
                int nTopRect,
                int nRightRect,
                int nBottomRect,
                int nWidthEllipse,
                int nHeightEllipse
             );

            private bool CheckIfAeroIsEnabled()
            {
                if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
                {
                    int enabled = 0;
                    DwmIsCompositionEnabled(ref enabled);

                    return (enabled == 1) ? true : false;
                }
                return false;
            }

            #endregion

            #region Overrides

            public void ApplyShadows(Form form)
            {
                var v = 2;

                DwmSetWindowAttribute(form.Handle, 2, ref v, 4);

                MARGINS margins = new MARGINS()
                {
                    bottomHeight = 1,
                    leftWidth = 0,
                    rightWidth = 0,
                    topHeight = 0
                };

                DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(form.Handle, ref margins);
            }

            #endregion

            #endregion

            #endregion
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new DropShadow().ApplyShadows(this);
        }
```

This code was grabbed from: [Border-less winform form shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60913399/border-less-winform-form-shadow/60916421#60916421)

Comment: I see no code nor any other indication that you have actually created an elliptical region for your form. Be warned. however: Winforms is bad at glitz..

Comment: im using WPF not winforms

Comment: Then your Tag is wrong!

Comment: ok sorry
Ill shange it